# Load Maperitive's tiles.json into HTML for getting bounding parameters

Tags: leaflet, json, offline, maperitive

I've created a local tileset of a city in Maperitive, and a basic leaflet.js webpage to browse it offline. There's a tiles.json also created by Maperitives that has all the essential bounding and zoom limits that I want.. at present am having to copy-paste them manually into the html file. Please show how to import the tiles.json and load the limits etc directly from there. This way a generic html is available that will display whatever content the tiles folder with it is carrying. (note: this isn't a typical GeoJSON.. doesn't have placemarks or polygons.)
HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet.css" />
</head>
  <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="lib/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [18.512224413095872, 73.868436919390348],
    zoom: 12,
    minZoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 15,
    maxBounds: [
    [18.443790655688225, 73.741131698096311],
    [18.672919555595893, 73.955365096533811]
    ]
});
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'Map tiles generated for local use by <a href="http://maperitive.net">Maperitive</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.' }).addTo(map);    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

tiles.json contents: (generated by Maperitive when generating tiles)

```
// Generated by Maperitive v2.3.32
// For more information about TileJSON format, visit https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson#readme
// TODO: Update the 'tiles' to reflect your actual path on the Web server
// TODO: Update the default map location (longitude, latitude, zoom)
{
    "tilejson":"1.0.0", 
    "name":"My Map", 
    "description":"Made with Maperitive", 
    "attribution":"Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors", 
    "tiles":
    [
        "tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    ], 
    "minzoom":8, 
    "maxzoom":15, 
    "bounds":
    [
        73.741131698096311, 
        18.443790655688225, 
        73.955365096533811, 
        18.672919555595893
    ], 
    "center":
    [
        73.848248397315061, 
        18.558355105642057, 
        8
    ]
}
```

Requirement : HTML should load the tiles.json file, and get the center, zoom, minZoom, maxZoom, maxBounds data from there rather than author having to manually type them in.

**Edit:** Since the tileJSON format has been created by Mapbox, I put this same use-case in another question, targeted at Mapbox, and some solutions seem to be coming together there. So please check out : [Load external tileJSON file in Mapbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130089/load-external-tilejson-file-in-mapbox)